# bot to send message to a different channel on same server

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to get my Discord bot to send a message to another channel when there is more than one item in the response, write a message to another channel (on the same server).  This code is within an async function and returns the first item of the response.

Currently, this code is sending to the channel where the command originated.  When I attempt things I've found to send to another channel, I get errors such as `fetch not being found` or `cache not being found`.  What am I missing to get this to work?

```
if(response.length > 1)
{
  let returnMessage = 'Items found: " + response.length;

  for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
  {
    let responseString = response[i].toString();
    returnMessage += "\r\n" + responseString.substring(responseString.indexOf('/', 10));
  }

  // send message to another channel here
  message.channel.send("test message"); // this sends the message to the current channel.
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Updated my question.  But essentially, I'm not sure what it is I'm doing incorrectly to get it to send to a different channel.  Insight would be great.

Comment: `const targetChannel = await message.guild.channels.fetch('CHANNEL_ID')` Then use `targetChannel.send()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing, and it appears to be working.

```
message.client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID').send('message');
```